# ServiceStack v4.0.60 does not have IRedisClientFactory

Tags: c#-4.0, servicestack

After upgrading ServiceStack from version 4.0.23 to 4.0.60 I got following error:

> The type or namespace name 'IRedisClientFactory' could not be found

I searched release notes for 2015 and 2016 and did not find anything about removing of IRedisClientFactory

But it was in 4.0.23

[image]

I will appreciate very much any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The interface that all [Redis Client Managers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) share is `IRedisClientsManager`.